# VBA Excel copy and paste the textbox to the speficied location

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy textbox to other location.

```
   Dim bonmb3a As Shape, bonmb3b As Shape
   Set bonmb3a = bow.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 14, 333, 47, 21)
    With bonmb3a
        .Name = "Building Overview Box 3A"
        With .line
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .Weight = 3
        End With
        With .TextFrame2
            .TextRange.Characters.Text = "3"
            .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
            With .TextRange.Characters.Font
                .Bold = msoTrue
                .size = 12
            End With
        End With
        .Copy
     End With
     Set bonmb3b = bonmb3a.Paste(550, 140, 47, 21)
```

but with the following code I can't see pasted object. No error shown.

How could I copy the textbox to the specified location?

Comment: Why copy/paste if you already have the code to create another from scratch?

Comment: I need to cut down the amount of code, as my project will be vast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Paste` without parameters.
After pasting, the new textbox is the last shape on the sheet. Then you can modify the properties you need, eg position (top + left) or name or caption.

```
bow.Paste
Set bonmb3b = bow.Shapes(bow.Shapes.Count)
With bonmb3b
    .Left = 550
    .Top = 140
    .Name = "Building Overview Box 3B"
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "4"
End With
```